# JPA : How to manage unmapped Table using Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have `@ManyToMany` relationship between two entities `A` and `B`, so Hibernate creates for me an unmapped table named `A_B` into the database which I don't have a related entity in my java code. Also, I'm trying to query that `A_B` table from my dao using Criteria API. Could someone help me please to figure out a solution? I'm trying to do something like this example in `Criteria API`:

`select * from A_B where A_B.column = id_input;`

Comment: You should provide your entities and a query expected result. You have to use entities instead of the database tables in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is mapping ORM. In JPA (using JPQL) you use fields of classes, so if you have relation in class, you can use it to create method name in repository. Example:

client entity:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;

}
```

and product entity with mark that relation is mapping from client enitity

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(name="name")
private String productName;
private String description;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="products")
private List<Client> clients;

}
```

Now repository to find clients by product name:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>{

List<Client> findByProducts_ProductName(String name);

}
```

Above example create join table with name `client_products` and columns `clients_id` and `products_id` - used field names to generate column names.
If you want to custom table name or column names, you have to map this on client entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="products_of_client",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="client_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
        )
private List<Product> products;
```

this change create table with name `products_of_client` and column names `client_id` and `product_id`. It does not affect on method name in repository

Comment: i'm not using spring Data (@Repository) i'm using the old way using persistense Unit and entityManager to implement the DAO logic

Comment: how you create query? HQL, criteria, or native SQL?

Comment: am using criteria API